# Batch Files, For Loop Not Echoing Line

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I have a problem here.
First things first, the code:

Contents of test.bat:

```
@echo off
cls
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /A-D ^| findstr /I ".txt$"') do (
set str=%%a
echo %str% >> list.tmp
pause
)

echo ------------------
for /F %%i in (list.tmp) do echo %%i
del list.tmp
echo ------------------
```

In the same directory where test.bat is, there are two test files:
1.txt and 2.txt

When I run test.bat, my output is:

```
------------------
2.txt
2.txt
------------------
```

As you can see, 1.txt isn't listed.

And when adding a 3.txt, the output is:

```
------------------
3.txt
3.txt
3.txt
------------------
```

Can anyone help me please??

Thanks,
Andrew Wong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to use *Delayed Expansion* feature, since within a `FOR` loop, you're reading a variable, and that variable is also modified in that loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cls
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /A-D ^| findstr /I ".txt$"') do (
  set str=%%a
  echo !str! >> list.tmp
  pause
)

echo ------------------
for /F %%i in (list.tmp) do echo %%i
del list.tmp
echo ------------------
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use a function (subRoutine)... That also "force" CMD to evaluate for each loop...

```
@echo off
cls
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /A-D ^| findstr /I ".txt$"') do (
  call :doOne %%a 
)

echo ------------------
for /F %%i in (list.tmp) do echo %%i
del list.tmp
echo ------------------
goto :EOF

:DoOne
  set str=%1
  echo %str% >> list.tmp
  pause
```